# phpmailer not perfomring action, downloading instead

Tags: phpmailer, contact-form

Good Evening,

I'm trying to send an e-mail to my personal e-mail address with phpmailer.  I'm creating a php file for the phpmailer and then I'm setting the form action to this file.  When I upload the page to my site and test it, instead of executing the action as it should it's downloading the file and not sending an e-mail.  Here is my code:

```
<form class="contactform" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="email.php" `   method="post" enctype="text/plain">
```

And the php file code:

```
<body>
<?php
require("class.PHPMailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "mail.50webs.com";  // specify main and backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "xxxxxx";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "xxxxxxxx*"; // SMTP password

$mail->From = "xxxxx";
$mail->FromName = "webmaster";
$mail->AddAddress("xxxxxx", "Bryan Sayles");
$mail->AddAddress("bxxxxxxxxx");                  // name is optional
$mail->AddReplyTo("xxxxxx", "Webmaster");

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->AddAttachment("/var/tmp/file.tar.gz");         // add attachments
$mail->AddAttachment("/tmp/image.jpg", "new.jpg");    // optional name
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = "Contact form response";
$mail->Body    = "$message $contactreason $name </b>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients";

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";
?>
</body>
```

I saw there is a similar question on here but my problem seems different as I didn't forget the  tags.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend reading the PHPMailer docs and following the example code it's bundled with. What you've posted will not work with a recent version of PHPMailer, so [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). The code you have is based on a very old, obsolete example, so I don't know where you got it from.

You don't say quite what you mean by "downloading the file", but I assume you mean that submitting your request displays your PHP code in your browser instead of running it. This means that your web server is not configured to serve PHP correctly, and that's [a question better suited to Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/search?q=php+display+source).

Comment: Hi Synchro, 
Thanks for your answer.  It doesn't display the code in the browser.  It downloads the file onto my computer so I can then open it up in my html editor.  I know that sounds weird and impossible but that's what happens.  I'll try the code you suggested on github.  Thanks.

Comment: Not impossible at all! Does the file it downloads contain the PHP source code? If so, it's still the same problem - your server is not set up to serve PHP.

Comment: yeah.  the downloaded file has the source code in it.  What would be a good web sever to use that allow php?

Comment: Any will do - you just need to configure it - follow the server fault link I gave you, and search.